# How to solve itext pdf Turkish character problem in jpanel

Tags: pdf, encoding, itext, turkish

I convert Jpanel to PDF using iText PDF, but certain special (Turkish) characters are not being displayed in the resulting PDF document.

My code is shown below:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));

document.open();
document.newPage();
Rectangle  rec = new Rectangle(0,0,panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
document.setPageSize(rec);

PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfGraphics2D g2 = new PdfGraphics2D(contentByte,panel.getWidth(),panel.getHeight());

panel.print(g2);
g2.dispose();
```

Comment: What characters are not shown?

Comment: the characters İ ş ı I Ş are not shown

Comment: Are those characters displayed as something else, or are they not shown at all?

Comment: They are not shown

Comment: Do you have access to the book *iText in Action 2e [2011]*?  That book has examples for handling non-English text (Japanese) starting on page 485.  There, it says you need to use the *BaseFontParameters* class. Maybe you can apply the same principles but use Turkish fonts. Here's a link to that book: https://b-ok.org/book/922465/013206
I am not a Java person myself.